# Software to solve equation

Tags: math-software, wolfram-alpha

I'm trying to solve the following equation:

\begin{align}
100.474 &=
\frac{1\cdot 1000}{\left(1+18.94833392\right)}   +\frac{1\cdot 1000}{\left(1+5.3028     \right)^ 2}+\\
&\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+3.29905    \right)^ 3}+\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+2.55048    \right)^ 4}+\\
&\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+2.16545    \right)^ 5}+\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+1.93226    \right)^ 6}+\\
&\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+1.77628    \right)^ 7}+\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+1.66477    \right)^ 8}+\\
&\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+1.58115    \right)^ 9}+\frac{1000\cdot 1}{\left(1+1.51614    \right)^{10}}+
\frac{1000\cdot 1+1000}{\left(1+x\right)^{15}}
\end{align}

However, my Wolfram Alpha is refusing to cooperate. Am I doing something wrong or is Wolfram Alpha just unable to solve it? If so, could you please point me to a different calculator?

Here is the [link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100.826%3D%5Cfrac%7B1%5Ccdot%201000%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B18.94833392%5Cright%29%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1%5Ccdot%201000%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B5.3028%5Cright%29%5E2%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B3.29905%5Cright%29%5E3%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B2.51701%5Cright%29%5E4%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B2.12996%5Cright%29%5E5%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B1.86945%5Cright%29%5E6%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%20%5C%3A1%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B1.67672%5Cright%29%5E7%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B1.59296%5Cright%29%5E8%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2B1.80615%5Cright%29%5E9%7D%2B%5Cfrac%7B1000%5Ccdot%201%2B1000%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%2Bx%5Cright%29%5E%7B10%7D%7D) to my calculations in WA:

Thanks

Comment: You might want to include the input/link you use in WA, you don't expect others to retype it

Comment: @Sil sorry, edited the post.

Comment: I believe the reason WA may be stuttering on this problem is due to the immense amounts of \frac and \cdot notation.

Comment: Don't put $\displaystyle\color{red}{\LaTeX}$ in W${\Large\alpha}$.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need software to solve the equation. It is of the form
$$A = B + \frac{2000}{(1+x)^{15}},$$
where $A, B > 0$ are constants independent of $x$, defined by the sums you have above. The solution is
$$x = \left(\frac{2000}{A-B}\right)^{1/15} - 1.$$